# jQuery click function inside click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, this is my first question here, so I want to Apologize in advance if it is repeated.

I have a piece of code like this:

```
$("#one").click(function(){ 
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    $("#two").click(function(event){
        console.log(randomNumber);
    });
});
```

First time everything is working fine, but second time i executed that It shows the first random number and then the second, etc.

Comment: Well, you're attaching a new click event handler to `#two` on each click of `#one` hence you see the `console.log` being executed multiple times. What behaviour are you trying to create?

Comment: You could use `$("#two").one('click', handler);` but surely you have better to do, depending what exact behaviour you are expecting, like e.g what are you expecting if clicking on #two before any click on #one???  And beware, here you are defining `randomNumber` on global scope

Comment: Well, you are right, I think I didn't explain the behaviour as well as I thought...

The behaviour I expect is: 
1. You click on #one and a random number is generated 
2. You click on #two and the random number is printed, but only if the first button was clicked, If not, the second button does nothing. Hope this explain better what I am trying to do...thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

When click on #one happens, randomNumber is generated and handler to the #two is assigned. This means that subsequent clicks on the #one add multiple handlers meaning that the code will be outputted more than once.

If you want to have only one handler you can do something like this

```
(function(){
     var randomNumber;
     $("#one").click(function(){
         randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
     });

     $("#two").click(function(){
         if(randomNumber){
             console.log(randomNumber);
         }
     });
})(}
```

EDIT: Added test for randomNumber, which means that it happens only after the first button was clicked. `

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much, but I think I didn't explain correctly what I want to do... sorry :(

The behaviour I expect is:

1. You click on #one and a random number is generated
2. You click on #two and the random number is printed, **but only if the first button was clicked**, If not, the second button does nothing.

Hope this explain better what I am trying to do...thanks a lot

Comment: Ok! Now I see what I was doing wrong...Thank you very much, I was totally stuck on this...and it was easier than I thought! :D

Answer (score 1):

> The behaviour I expect is: 1. You click on #one and a random number is
>   generated 2. You click on #two and the random number is printed, but
>   only if the first button was clicked, If not, the second button does
>   nothing.

You can use [`.off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method to remove previously bound event handlers. This will prevent the double or even multiple "*shows the first random number and then the second, etc*"

```
$("#one").on('click', function(){ 
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    $("#two").off('click').on('click', function(event){ // Preserve other event handlers if any.
        console.log(randomNumber);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#one").click(function(){ 
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
    $("#two").click(function(event){
        console.log(randomNumber);
    });
  });
});
```